# Woocommerce + qTranslate-X attributes are not saved after product update

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, qtranslate-x

i am using:

WooCommerce – Version 2.5.5

WooCommerce & qTranslate-X – Version 1.3.1

qTranslate-X – Version 3.4.6.7

It's a fresh installation.

After setting up custom product attributes (also normal product attributes), saving them and publishing the product they disappear.
Without qTranslate-X activated everything is working normally.

I found a lot about not translated attributes, but no information about not shown attribues at all.

- php memory is not a problem, i already checked it,
- i downgraded all plugins and reinstalled them
- i deleted all attributes and products and reseted them

Comment: Check that: [**qTranslate-X known issues with wooCommerce**](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-qtranslate-x/other_notes/)… Check also [qTranslate-X support threads](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce-qtranslate-x) searching or opening a thread.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to translate custom product attributes with WooCommerce & qTranslate-X you need to use raw multilingual format.

Example:

[:en]My Custom Field#1[:it]Attributo personalizzato #1[:]

Here is the FAQ of the qTranslate plugin
https://qtranslatexteam.wordpress.com/faq